# How should I be storing expiring stats?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, statistics

Let's say I have 2 models in my app: `User` and `Survey`

I'm trying to plot the number of paid surveys over time. A paid survey is one that has been created by a user that has an active subscription. For simplicity, let's assume the `User` model has `subscription_start_date` and `subscription_end_date`.

So a survey becomes "paid" the moment it is created (provided the user has an active subscription) and loses its "paid" status when the `subscription_end_date` has passed. Essentially, the "paid survey" is really a state with a defined start and end date.

I can generate the data fine. What I'm curious about is what's the most recommended way of storing this kind of stats? What should that table look like basically.

Another thing I'm concerned about is whether there are any disadvantages of having a daily task that adds the data point for the past day.

For more context, this app is written in Rails and we're thinking of using this stat architecture for other models too.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, I do not think you need an additional model or daily task to generate data points. To generate your report you just need to come up with the right SQL/ActiveRecord query. When you aggregate the information, be careful not to introduce nested queries. For simplicity's sake we could pull all the information you need using:

```rb
surveys = Survey.all.includes(:user)
```

Based on your description, an instance of survey has a start date that is just `created_at.to_date`. And since `Survey` `belongs_to :user`, it's end date is `user.subscription_end_date`.

When plotting the information you may need to transform `surveys` into some data structure that groups the information by date. Alternatively you could probably achieve that with a more complex SQL statement.

You could of course introduce a new table that stores the data points by date to avoid a complex query or data aggregation via ruby. The downside of this is that you are storing redundant information and assume the burden of maintaining data integrity. That doesn't mean you shouldn't do it because there may be an upside in regards to performance and reporting convenience.

I would need more information about your project before saying exactly what I would do, but it sounds like you already have the information you need in your database and it's just a matter querying it properly.